# Evaluate the derivative of numpy chebychev polynomial

Tags: python, numpy

How can I evaluate the derivative of `numpy` chebychev polynomials? I'm finding it to be very unintuitive. It looks like this option is not provided by `chebval` at all. Loking at [numpy's docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html) (at the end of the calculus section), this is the most reasonable-seeming thing I've tried:

```
> import numpy as np
> xf = 3
> P = np.polynomial.Chebyshev([0, xf])
> P(np.linspace(0, 3, 5))
array([0.        , 2.35619449, 4.71238898, 7.06858347, 9.42477796])
> P(np.linspace(0, 3, 5)).deriv(1)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'deriv'
```

I also can't seem to feed `np.polynomial.Chebyshev` coefficients. I can only do that with `chebval`.

```
P(np.linspace(0, 3, 5), [1,2,3])
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm actually confused about the docs too. How do I feed `np.polynomial.Chebyshev` coefficients? `chebval` is much more intuitive:

```
> np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebval(np.linspace(0, 3, 5), [3, 2, 1])
array([ 2.   ,  4.625,  9.5  , 16.625, 26.   ])
> np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebval(np.linspace(0, 3, 5), [3, 2, 1]).deriv(1)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'deriv'
```

So, I am confused. How can I feed numpy chebychev coefficients and x points and get the derivative back, like `chebval` lets me evaluate the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the derivative of the *polynomial itself*. That'd be `P` here:

```
P.deriv()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you show an example where you feed it coefficients and x-points then take the derivative please?

Comment: @kilojoules: Other way around: take the derivative, *then* evaluate, same as in math. You don't evaluate a polynomial at a point, get a constant, and then try to take the derivative of the constant.

Comment: I don't know how to feed `np.polynomial.Chebyshev` coefficients. In my best solution so far, I failed to provide coefficients.

Comment: @kilojoules: One question per question please. Also, [read the `Chebyshev` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev.html#numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev).

Comment: OK. I made another question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200245/how-do-i-feed-numpy-polynomial-chebyshev-chebyshev-coefficients