# How do I feed numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev coefficients?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I feed `np.polynomial.Chebyshev` coefficients? I'm finding the API to be unintuitive. It looks like it is assuming some coefficient values

```
> import numpy as np
> xf = 3
> P = np.polynomial.Chebyshev([0, xf]) # domain is [0, xf]
> P(np.linspace(0, 3, 5)) # evaluate at 5 x-points evenly spaced from 0 to 3
array([0.        , 2.35619449, 4.71238898, 7.06858347, 9.42477796])
P(np.linspace(0, 3, 5), [1,2,3]) # evaluate the points with prescribed coefficients, implicitly asking for polynomials of 4 degrees 
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Chebyshev docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev.html#numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev), you'll find that the first argument is the coefficients, not the domain. The domain is the optional second argument. For example,

```
np.polynomial.Chebyshev([0, 3])
```

is `0*T_0 + 3*T_1`.